# Compile Qt open source fails during gmake

Tags: c++, qt, cross-compiling

I am building qt open source to be used for cross-compile. The configure command works fine, and gmake starts but fails as shown below. This makes no sense since the pthread.h is included and defines the macro being sought. There must be something else going on. Can someone suggest how to fix this?

```
gmake[3]: Entering directory '/root/raspi/qt-build/qtbase/src/3rdparty/pcre2'
/root/raspi/arm-gnu-toolchain-12.2.mpacbti-rel1-x86_64-arm-none-eabi/bin/arm-none-eabi-gcc -c -march=armv8-a -mtune=cortex-a53 -mfpu=crypto-neon-fp-armv8 --sysroot=/root/raspi/sysroot -O2 -fPIC -std=gnu11 -fvisibility=hidden -w -fno-exceptions -DQT_NO_LINKED_LIST -DQT_NO_JAVA_STYLE_ITERATORS -DPCRE2_CODE_UNIT_WIDTH=16 -DQT_NO_NARROWING_CONVERSIONS_IN_CONNECT -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DQT_NO_DYNAMIC_CAST -DQT_NO_EXCEPTIONS -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -I/root/raspi/qt-everywhere-src-5.15.9/qtbase/src/3rdparty/pcre2 -I. -I/root/raspi/qt-everywhere-src-5.15.9/qtbase/src/3rdparty/pcre2/src -I/root/raspi/qt-everywhere-src-5.15.9/qtbase/mkspecs/devices/linux-rasp-pi3-g++ -o .obj/pcre2_jit_compile.o /root/raspi/qt-everywhere-src-5.15.9/qtbase/src/3rdparty/pcre2/src/pcre2_jit_compile.c
In file included from /root/raspi/qt-everywhere-src-5.15.9/qtbase/src/3rdparty/pcre2/src/sljit/sljitLir.c:260,
                 from /root/raspi/qt-everywhere-src-5.15.9/qtbase/src/3rdparty/pcre2/src/pcre2_jit_compile.c:79:
/root/raspi/qt-everywhere-src-5.15.9/qtbase/src/3rdparty/pcre2/src/sljit/sljitUtils.c:41:41: error: 'PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER' undeclared here (not in a function)
   41 | static pthread_mutex_t allocator_lock = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
      |                                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/root/raspi/qt-everywhere-src-5.15.9/qtbase/src/3rdparty/pcre2/src/sljit/sljitUtils.c:77:10: fatal error: sys/mman.h: No such file or directory
   77 | #include <sys/mman.h>
```

A couple of lines from the source file causing the first error are as follows:

```
#include <pthread.h>
static pthread_mutex_t allocator_lock = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
```

So the error makes no sense to me. How can this fail? And the second error makes no sense since the mman.h file exists where it is supposed to.   Gmake is pretty far along and lots of other subprojects have compiled fine, so it's not like the include path is completely wrong.

Here's the location of the two header files in question:

```
[root@fedora qt-build]# find /root/raspi -name mman.h | grep sys
/root/raspi/sysroot/usr/include/aarch64-linux-gnu/asm/mman.h
/root/raspi/sysroot/usr/include/aarch64-linux-gnu/bits/mman.h
/root/raspi/sysroot/usr/include/aarch64-linux-gnu/sys/mman.h
/root/raspi/sysroot/usr/include/asm-generic/mman.h
/root/raspi/sysroot/usr/include/linux/mman.h
/root/raspi/qt-everywhere-src-5.15.9/qtwebengine/src/3rdparty/chromium/third_party/crashpad/crashpad/compat/android/sys/mman.h
/root/raspi/qt-everywhere-src-5.15.9/qtwebengine/src/3rdparty/chromium/third_party/crashpad/crashpad/compat/linux/sys/mman.h
[root@fedora qt-build]# find /root/raspi -name pthread.h
/root/raspi/sysroot/usr/include/pthread.h
/root/raspi/arm-gnu-toolchain-12.2.mpacbti-rel1-x86_64-arm-none-eabi/arm-none-eabi/include/pthread.h
```

Comment: "exists where it's supposed to" == under the `/root/raspi/sysroot` sysroot? Also, don't compile stuff as root.

Comment: I added the file locations to my question.  But I still don't understand how the pthread.h contents are not used/included.  I am working as root to confirm no permission problem, but will not use elevated account one I have this working.

Comment: Your compiler triple seems to be `arm-none-eabi`. Why do you expect gcc to look for headers under `... /usr/include/aarch64-linux-gnu`? Unless you can prove that gcc searches that for headers there (`arm-none-eabi-gcc -v` or some such)

Comment: @Botje I'm not sure about the order of where the compiler looks for headers, but the pthread.h is on the include path (and it is found), yet the compiler says it doesn't know about the macro defined in the pthread. file.  Can't understand that

Comment: You can ask the compiler about its standard include paths with `.../arm-none-eabi-gcc -v`. By default it  looks for `/usr/include/$TRIPLE`, where TRIPLE is "arm-none-eabi" instead of "aarch64-linux-gnu"

Comment: As for the pthread problem, did you verify that the define has an `#ifdef` guard? I took a look at my own copy of pthread.h and it is always defined but I have no idea where you got yours.

Comment: It is always defined in my pthread.h so I can't explain this